# Emacs gfortran compilation exits abnormally with code 1

Tags: emacs, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm attempting to use gfortran to compile a simple Fortran hello world script. It compiles nicely in the Windows console, but not in Emacs. Is this related to its environment? I'm not using any libraries. Any help understanding why would be greatly appreciated.

Simple "Hello World":

```
Program Hello
Print *, "Hello World!"
End Program Hello
```

Here is the compile command, using M-x compile:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe C:\emacs\fortran\hello.f -o C:\emacs\fortran\hello.exe
```

Emacs reports this error:

```
Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri May 10 18:10:15
```

Thank you,

Comment: Thanks! Quick update - it did work when I navigated to the compiler to make it the current directory. Just a bit of a pain if I'm editing a script in another folder, unless I use a different buffer for the compiler.

Comment: Yes, M-x compile, then choosing which compiler to run in the compile command like in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify your compile command, you can add the path to `gfortran` to your `exec-path` which should allow the compiler to be found (test with `(executable-find "gfortran")`,

`(cl-pushnew "path/to/mingw/bin" exec-path :test #'equal)`

You can also set a default `compile-command` in your `fortran-mode-hook`, eg. to compile the current file with some default flags (modify for windows) you could use something like,

```
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook #'my-fortran-hook)

(defun my-fortran-hook ()
  (setq-local
   compile-command
   (format "gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fbounds-check -g -std=f95 -Ofast -o %s %s"
           (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
           (buffer-file-name))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect, but when I try using (cl-pushnew exec-path "C:/MinGW/bin" :test #'equal) it gives me an error saying "%S is not a valid place expression: C:/MinGW/bin"